# How to create an email alert for a procedure if it does not finish within 5 minutes?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, alert

I need to create an email alert for when a user is running a procedure in our application but the procedure is not finishing. I know how to generate the email but how do I write code that checks for when that procedure is running and determine if it has been running for longer than 5 minutes?

I have researched all of the dbms utilities but nothing comes close to what I am looking for.

Also I know how to put the long running sessions but my issue here is I am only interested in one procedure and from what I gather the sqlid can change. That is the way I was going to do it but since that changes how would I know if the user is running that procedure or they are running something else. I could pull the user session id but they could be running multiple procedures at the same time. How do I know which one is my target procedure?

Comment: I did search but nothing has come close to what I am looking for.  Should I list out my research for you?

Comment: I posted it because I don't believe you researched anything prior to coming here and asking for a solution. 'Oracle find long running queries' in Google is a great start.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from so I will leave it at that.  I did google that and I see where it can look at long running sessions but I am only interested in one procedure when it is run.  We have hundreds of sessions that are active and I need to find the one session or multiple if there are for a specific procedure.  I will keep looking.

Comment: An approach to consider is to have the procedure write its start time and process ID to a status table and remove that when it completes.  A separate process can check that table at whatever frequency you desire, and if it finds an entry that's been running longer than 5 minutes, send an email--and maybe kill the process if appropriate.

Comment: I like the idea.  I will give that a try.  I think I can also grab the sqltext from v$sqlarea so I make sure I am monitoring the correct procedure.  Thanks rd_nielsen!

Comment: Consider transactions when you write anything into a status table. I think you should use autonomous transaction for that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a dedicated status table you could also use package [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS003).

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('Starting at '||TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'Starting procedure');

... your actual procedure

-- If you like you can set intermediate updates at any time:
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION('Still running...');

DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(NULL, NULL);
```

While procedure is running you can query it by

```
SELECT SID, SERIAL#, USERNAME, OSUSER, MODULE, ACTION
from V$SESSION
where USERNAME = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run two procedures (different sessions), one that run your script/program and other that checks if the other program was already done running.

Below is the script that checks if the other program already done running after 5 minutes.

```
DECLARE
    var VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
    DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(300);
    BEGIN
        SELECT column_if_has_value_means_program_was_done
          INTO var
          FROM some_table_that_your_procedure_will_update;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            NULL;
    END;
    IF var IS NULL THEN
        SEND_EMAIL_PROCEDURE;
    END IF;
END;
/
```